# Angular - How to pass data from a pop up to element in angular app parent

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, get, popup

I am working on an application that is using angular and must allow users to retrieve data from a USPS api for address validation/standardization and zip4 retrieval. In the parent page, I am using the window.open functionality to open the popup window...

Popup page  (getAddress.php):

$value = $_GET['value']; echo('');

```
            $url = 'http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=';
            $msg = '<AddressValidateRequest USERID="xxxxxxxx" PASSWORD="">';  
            $msg .= '<Address ID="0"><Address1>';
            $msg .= $_GET['address1'];
            $msg .= '</Address1><Address2>';
            $msg .= $_GET['address2'];
            $msg .= '</Address2><City>';
            $msg .= $_GET['city'];
            $msg .= '</City><State>';
            $msg .= $_GET['state'];
            $msg .= '</State><Zip5>';
            $msg .= $_GET['zip'];
            $msg .= '</Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>';

        //get the response from the USPS
        $newurl = $url . urlencode($msg);
        $xml = $newurl;
        $parser = xml_parser_create();
        // open a file and read data
        $fp = fopen($xml, 'r');
        $xmldata = fread($fp, 4096);


        $xml_xmldata = new DOMDocument;

        $xml_xmldata->loadXML($xmldata);
        $sxe = simplexml_import_dom($xml_xmldata);

        if((!$sxe->Address[0]->Error)&&(!$sxe->Address[1]))
        {           
        $i=0;
```

This page works fine for retrieving the data we need. It pops up with either a matched address or an error message from the postal service if the address can't be found....

```
         echo '<div>Address Found</div>';
        echo '<div id="usps_addresses">';
        foreach($sxe as $nodes){
        echo '<p><span id="address1_'.$i.'">'.ucwords(strtolower($sxe->Address[$i]->Address1)).'</span><span id="address2_'.$i.'">'.ucwords(strtolower($sxe->Address[$i]->Address2));
        echo '</span><span id="city_'.$i.'">'.ucwords(strtolower($sxe->Address[$i]->City)).'</span><span id="state_'.$i.'">'.$sxe->Address[$i]->State;
        echo '</span><zip5 id="zip5_'.$i.'">'.$sxe->Address[$i]->Zip5.'</zip5>-<zip4 id="zip4_'.$i.'">'.$sxe->Address[$i]->Zip4.'</zip4>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo '<a href="" id="'.$i.'">SELECT</a>';
        echo '</p>';
         $i++;
         }
         if($sxe->Address[0]->ReturnText){
         echo $sxe->Address[0]->ReturnText;
         }

         }
         else{
            echo 'Error occurred.<br/><br/>';
            echo $sxe->Address[0]->Error[0]->Description;
         }

         echo '</div>';
        echo '</body></html>'
```

If the correct address is found, the user clicks the SELECT link, and the address data is placed in the parent window....
I have a click event handler for the anchor that has the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        var myID = this.id;

        var addressType = document.getElementById("type").value;
        //alert(addressType);

        var myAddress1 = document.getElementById("address1_" + myID).innerHTML;
        var myAddress2 = document.getElementById("address2_" + myID).innerHTML;
        var myCity = document.getElementById("city_" + myID).innerHTML;
        var myState = document.getElementById("state_" + myID).innerHTML;
        var myZip5 = document.getElementById("zip5_" + myID).innerHTML;
        var myZip4 = document.getElementById("zip4_" + myID).innerHTML;
        window.opener.$("#mem-address").address.addresses[myID].zip4 = myZip4;

          window.opener.$scope.address.addresses[myID].zip4 = myZip4;      
        window.opener.$("#Address1_"+addressType).val(myAddress1).removeClass('error');
        window.opener.$("#Address2_"+addressType).val(myAddress2).removeClass('error');
        window.opener.$("#City_"+addressType).val(myCity).removeClass('error');
        window.opener.$("#State_"+addressType).val(myState).removeClass('error');
        window.opener.$("#Zip5_"+addressType).val(myZip5).removeClass('error');           
        window.opener.$("#Zip4_"+addressType).val(myZip4).removeClass('error');


      window.close();
    })
})
```

But now, because I am using angular, and the elements inside the repeater cannot have id's, I am not able to get the data. I did a test and was able to get the $sxe string into localStorage, and it looks great, but I know there must be a way to access the parent elements.

HTML page:

references to jquery, angular, css...all that

```
    <div ng-hide='foundMember'>
    <button type='button' ng-click='addMember()'>Add Member</button><button type='button' ng-click='clearMember()'>Clear Member</button>
</div>
    <div>
        <member-lookup ></member-lookup>
        <label>Edit Mode:</label>
        <select ng-model='editMode'
                ng-options='mode.label for mode in modes'></select>
    </div>

    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <member-data ></member-data>
    </div>      


    <div class='col-md-4'>          
            <address-data id='mem-address'></address-data>          
        <hr>            
            <phone-data></phone-data>           
        </div>

    <div class='col-md-4'>          
            <email-data></email-data>
    <hr>        
            <beneficiary-data></beneficiary-data>           
    </div>

</div> <!-- End of content  -->
```

I need the data to go into a repeater inside the directive that creates the address-data tags I created.

As you can see, I attempted to add an id to the address-data tag to reference it, but I am stuck on how to get inside the functionality of the address-data.

TRIED:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        var myID = this.id;

        //

        var addressType = document.getElementById("type").value;
        //alert(addressType);

        var myAddress1 = document.getElementById("address1_" + myID).innerHTML;
        var myAddress2 = document.getElementById("address2_" + myID).innerHTML;
        var myCity = document.getElementById("city_" + myID).innerHTML;
        var myState = document.getElementById("state_" + myID).innerHTML;
        var myZip5 = document.getElementById("zip5_" + myID).innerHTML;
        var myZip4 = document.getElementById("zip4_" + myID).innerHTML;

        var myJSON = [{address1:myAddress1,address2:myAddress2,city:myCity,state:myState,zip5:myZip5,zip4:myZip4}];
```

window.opener.$("#mem-address").addresses[myID] = myJSON;

window.close();

to create an object with keys that match the directive that creates the address-data tags. But it's not working. I am a new, struggling developer and would appreciate any help.

GOAL: 
Users will be editing data that is pulled from the database, or creating new address records. New address records require the zip4, but I would like to allow users the option to standardize the address before persisting to the database.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `$scope` of an element like this: `angular.element('your-selector').scope()`

So, in your case, you would do:

```
var addressScope = angular.element(window.opener.$("#mem-address")).scope();
```

Once you have the scope object, you can do whatever you want with it. Without knowing anything about how your scope is setup, you can probably do something like this:

```
addressScope.addresses = myJSON
```